# sale.order.line Quantity Update

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to do a "monthly" recurring bill, that is: 
- test_months, is the number of months to bill;
- the line quantity shall be = to test_months;

So, I trying to get "line quantity" updates, whenever the test_months onchange, but all order lines are removed?

My code:

```
class test_sale_order_line(osv.osv): _name = 'sale.order.line' _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def _test_product_uom_qty_line(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        res = {}

        if context is None:
            context = {}

        if not test_months:
            test_months = 1

        for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res = { 'product_uom_qty': 0.0 }
            res['product_uom_qty'] = test_months

        return res

    _columns = {
        'product_uom_qty': fields.function(_test_product_uom_qty_line, string='Quantity', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product UoS'), required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
    }

test_sale_order_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Recurring invoice module from OpenERP, as it is more easy to do recurring billing using it instead of making something from a scratch.

Cheers,
Parthiv

Comment: can someone tell me how to get "line quantity" updates, whenever the test_months onchange?